# Clones of the "are the stormtroopers clones?" question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The following questions are very similar to each other:

1. [Are Imperial Storm Troopers all clones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5801/31936)
2. [What canon evidence is there that Stormtroopers are/are not still clones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41198/31936)
3. [Is it widely known that Stormtroopers are clones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/47614/31936)

I would say that (1) and (2) are duplicates, and (3) is close enough that it might be worth closing as a duplicate.

The real question, in my mind, is: which question(s) should be marked as the duplicates?

(1) was asked first so (2) was a duplicate when it was asked. However, I propose closing (1) as a duplicate of (2) because the accepted answer to (1), while correct, is based on an outdated, non-canon source (it cites a Wookieepedia article which in turn cites a video game). However, now that Disney is handling *Star Wars* canon they have confirmed canonically -- both in and out of universe -- that the clones were  quickly phased out of the Stormtrooper Corps. [My (accepted) answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72400/31936) to (2) provides these updated canon sources and therefore, in my opinion, we should use (2) as the main version of the question and close (1). I did post an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94056/31936) to (1) with the updated canon information, but visitors are unlikely to see it since it has not been accepted and has a much lower score than the accepted answer.

As for (3), it's not an exact duplicate but is based on the false premise that the stormtroopers were clones throughout the Empire's existence. Should (3) be marked as a duplicate? I'm inclined to leave it open since it also asks about the attitudes of Imperial citizens. The accepted answer by @phantom42 is out of date (perhaps he'd like to update it?) but makes good points about the attitudes and knowledge of Imperial citizens.

What say you?

Comment: My question isn't a dupe. The oldest question asks based on EU info. Mine asked specifically about g-canon evidence. I see them as greatly related, but not dupes.

Comment: I don't see anything in (1) which indicates that it was looking for non-canon information. The answer that was accepted used non-canon information, but that's because no one had canon proof at the time. At this point in time, the two questions are effectively duplicates. I think we should close one, and I think it should be the older one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 1 should be closed as a dupe of 2.  That we have a complete answer on the nature of the Troopers several years (and a canon change) later means the answers on the old question are kinda deprecated, but still of historical value.

3 is asking a different enough question that I don't think it's a duplicate.  3 is asking about in universe common knowledge of the provenance of the Storm Troopers. That the asker misunderstood that the troopers aren't clones provides some overlap with the other questions, but the piece about what the common knowledge of Troopers is makes it sufficiently distinct from the other questions.